# Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC at /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN/FirstTime.pm

Tags: perl, ubuntu-12.04, perl-module, cpan

I am trying to use Perl the **first time** on my system which is Ubuntu 12.04. I have Perl v.5.14.2 installed.
I looked up [how to install Perl modules](http://perl.about.com/od/packagesmodules/qt/perlcpan.htm), so I started as follows:

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

The wizard started configuring the environment as can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/5hn8vkb5
Though, it stopped in the middle with the following error message:

```
...

Checksum for /home/john/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AP/APEIRON/local-lib-1.008009.tar.gz ok
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----     APEIRON/local-lib-1.008009.tar.gz    ----
    ExtUtils::MakeMaker [build_requires]
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
  Delayed until after prerequisites

Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
    /home/john/perl5/lib/perl5
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.14
    /usr/share/perl/5.14
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    /home/john/Desktop)
at /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN/FirstTime.pm line 1300.
```

What can I do to setup the Perl environment correctly on my Ubuntu installation?

---

After interrupting the wizard and restarting it again, there is no error message anymore.
How can I start the wizard again so I can choose here:

> What approach do you want?  (Choose 'local::lib', 'sudo' or 'manual') 
>   [local::lib]

Comment: `cpan local::lib` perhaps? Or check the apt-get repository. You don't have that module installed, but you selected to use it as the means to install modules. You don't want to `sudo`?

Comment: @TLP What would be the name of the library I need to install via `sudo apt-get install ...`?

Comment: Beats me. You'll have to search. But you can of course do `sudo cpan local::lib`. Or?

Comment: `$ apt-cache search local-lib` returns:`liblocal-lib-perl - module to use a local path for Perl modules`. You might not get this error if you try: `$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell`

Comment: @TLP @chrsblck I did run `sudo cpan local::lib` and `sudo apt-get install liblocal-lib-perl`. However, the wizard error was gone before - see my updated question? How can I restart the wizard?

Comment: @JJD Not sure, I'll bet you can `rm -rf ~/.cpan`, if you haven't installed anything yet. I would recommend trying `cpanminus` instead of the old `CPAN` shell. NOTE: `rm -rf` at your own risk! Not positive that won't mess something up ;)

Comment: Yes, I also found `cpanminus` and successfully installed modules using the `--sudo` option. If you don't mind formulate your comments as an answer so I close this question then.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're missing `local::lib`, which is what you told `CPAN` shell to do.

You can install it like so:

```
sudo apt-get install liblocal-lib-perl
```

You might be able to start over by `rm -rf`-ing your `~/.cpan` directory. AT YOUR OWN RISK

However, I would recommend trying `cpanminus` instead of the old `CPAN shell`.

```
sudo apt-get install cpanminus
```

Comment: Sadly, neither `liblocal-lib-perl` or `cpanminus` is packaged in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - output from Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS: `$ apt-cache search liblocal-lib-perl
liblocal-lib-perl - module to use a local path for Perl modules` and `$ apt-cache search cpanminus
cpanminus - script to get, unpack, build and install modules from CPAN`

Comment: ...not so much, by contrast, on the official `ubuntu:12.04` docker image.

Comment: Ahh -- said docker image only contains main. I'm guessing these are elsewhere (universe or such)?

Comment: `liblocal-lib-perl` is definitely packaged for Ubuntu LTS 12.04.3. I just installed it.

Comment: I am always getting an error: **debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (you may need to install the strict module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl**

Answer (score 2):

The *local* namespace was for your own personal modules and wouldn't be found in CPAN. This is something relatively new. At many sites, you might need CPAN modules not in the current version of Perl, or you need a newer version of a particular module. However, you don't have write access to the standard location where CPAN modules are installed.

What this is doing is installing these modules under the `$HOME/perl5/lib/local` directory where you'll be able to access them. You would also need to setup a `PERL5LIB` environment variable (usually in your startup scripts), so Perl will check this directory when locating these modules.

If you have `sudo` privileges, use that to install CPAN modules rather than trying this. The following will install the `Foo::Bar` module into the standard module directory for you (and do any configuration as necessary):

```
$ sudo cpan install Foo::Bar
```

If CPAN needs to be configured, it will do that first.

There are complete directions on doing the *local::lib* install for modules on [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/APEIRON/local-lib-1.008009/lib/local/lib.pm). They're pretty clear.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explainations. I noticed that modules are installed locally but haven't been accessible in the PATH for Perl. Therefore, I tried `--sudo`. Thank you for the link, too.

Answer (score 2):

Several New OS's force (like Redhat 7) force to check presence of local::lib in the perl version, actually its a good thing this enables to users to use CPAN and add,experiment and enjoy new modules to be used with the perl without waiting for sitewide installation (like a root user). By default local::lib looks for $HOME/perl5 dir where the user's local or downloaded modules are located. If you see this problem then you have to do following

1. sudo su - whatever_user_owns_perl
2. whatever_perl_install_path/cpan install local::lib

Comment: " perl_install_path/cpan install local::lib " this work for me