# Perl Compilation Error: "Can't locate local/lib.pm"

Tags: perl, cpan

As a Perl rookie, I have made a rookie mistake.

I was working on a project that required an HTML parser so I thought I'd install Perl's HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath module, so I dove into cpan and perlbrew without a full understanding of how they work. I created a local library, but would like to return everything back to default. However, I get this error every time I open a terminal window (twice, for some reason):

```
Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/Users/James/perl5/lib/perl5
/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/5.12
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12 
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4
/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.12
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

I've seen the similar StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702642/cant-locate-local-lib-pm-in-inc-at-usr-share-perl-5-14-cpan-firsttime-pm) but I do not have `apt-get` installed.

How can I reset my machine so that this error no longer appears and it uses the default library?

Comment: You have a `use local::lib` somewhere, and you don't need it any longer if you have everything installed normally

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `local::lib` installation instructions tell you to add a line to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.  From your error, it looks like the line

```
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
```

is still present.  Look for it and remove it.

Comment: Ah, yes! This is it. It was actually in `.bash_profile`. Removed it and no more error. Thanks so much!

Comment: I also had the same issue when I installed heroku autocomplete using brew.

Answer (score 0):

For me this meant I had an earlier aborted run of cpan's installation.

fix: remove ~/.cpan and ~/perl5 dirs, and remove anything about them from .bashrc, and do it again...

Comment: I have the very same issue, I removed those directories, but the issue remains the same.